# Create subversion log file on build in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn

Is there a way to auto create a subversion log file when i build my project in visual studio?  I'm using AnkhSVN to intergrate SVN into visual studio.  I can manually run the svn log command to generate a log file but i'd like to auto create a release notes file every time i build the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Ankh.  However, if you can write a log manually, try writing a batch script that will run the same command, then have VS run the batch file in from the build steps.  You can find the build steps in the project properties.

I'm pretty sure this will work.  I used the build steps in VS at one time to automatically call an exe that would generate 3D models that would be loaded by the main executable compiled by VS.

Here's a link to msdn that might help:
[Specifying Custom Build Steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hefydhhy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Build events might be a better choise, they are in the same vein and there is a "Post-Build event" that is probably when you want to fire your script.  I think you can also just run it as a standalone command if you don't want to have to run a batch script.